# How can I see the romance cards I have won in Witcher?

Tags: the-witcher

I have just begun this game. I get the idea of how to obtain the cards, but is there a way to view all the cards I have won?

Comment: Heh..."romance cards".  Understatement of the year  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can view the cards you have won by going to the Character section of the journal screen (`J`). If a character has an associated card, a small heart will appear at the bottom left corner. Click on it to see the card.